# Friction in tyre with low air pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, everyday-life

I was driving a normal hatchback with right side tire with nearly half of advised pressure. Now everything was fine until i experienced that when surface is wet and i try to take turn on incline, right tire feels very powerless and making car stall when tires are turned to right, but are fine if I go straight.

I am not sure if it is physics question or automobile, but wont less air would have more friction and tyre have more grip?

Comment: Many things can be happening here - loss of contact with the road, collapse of sidewall shape, etc. that can lead to near-zero friction and thus the differential, if a limited-slip type, stalls on the outboard (left) tire.